# How to create war files

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, war

What are the best practices of creating war files (using eclipse) to run on tomcat? tutorials, links, examples are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) to set up, compile, [WAR](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html), and deploy your solution.

```
<target name="default" depends="setup,compile,buildwar,deploy"></target>
```

You can then execute one click in Eclipse to run that Ant target. Here are examples of each of the steps:

#### Preconditions

We'll assume that you have your code organized like:

- `${basedir}/src`: Java files, properties, XML config files
- `${basedir}/web`: Your JSP files
- `${basedir}/web/lib`: Any JARs required at runtime
- `${basedir}/web/META-INF`: Your manifest
- `${basedir}/web/WEB-INF`: Your web.xml files

#### Set up

Define a `setup` task that creates the distribution directory and copies any artifacts that need to be WARred directly:

```
<target name="setup">
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <echo>Copying web into dist</echo>
    <copydir dest="dist/web" src="web" />
    <copydir dest="dist/web/WEB-INF/lib" src="${basedir}/../web/WEB-INF/lib" />
</target>
```

#### Compile

Build your Java files into classes and copy over any non-Java artifacts that reside under `src` but need to be available at runtime (e.g. properties, XML files, etc.):

```
<target name="compile">
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <javac destdir="${dist.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes" srcdir="src">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/../web/WEB-INF/lib">
                  <include name="*" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${dist.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.properties" />
            <include name="**/*.xml" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

#### Build WAR

Create the WAR itself:

```
<target name="buildwar">
    <war basedir="${basedir}/dist/web" destfile="My.war"
     webxml="${basedir}/dist/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
        <webinf dir="${basedir}/dist/web/WEB-INF/">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </webinf>
    </war>
</target>
```

#### Deploy

Finally, you can set up a task to deploy the WAR directly into your Tomcat deploy location:

```
<target name="deploy">
    <copy file="My.war" todir="${tomcat.deploydir}" />
</target>
```

#### Click and go!

Once all this is set up, simply launching the `default` target from Eclipse will compile, WAR, and deploy your solution.

The advantage of this approach is that it will work outside Eclipse as well as within Eclipse and can be used to easily share your deployment strategy (e.g. via source control) with other developers who are also working on your project.

Comment: well I want to deploy it to tomcat. How should I change the targer?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? As long as ${tomcat.deploydir} points to your Tomcat context deployment directory, that should do it. No?

Comment: In the war target there is unnecessary '<exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />'. You have generated *.class files into this folder and excluding them does not work. Remove this exclude line from the war target it works.

Comment: This answer is needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 38):

I've always just selected Export from Eclipse.  It builds the war file and includes all necessary files.  Providing you created the project as a web project that's all you'll need to do.  Eclipse makes it very simple to do.

Comment: Thanks! and for what it's worth, you select "Export" from the "File" menu, then in "Select an Export Destination" type "WAR" and the war file option will come up.

Comment: my choice for quick and dirty web apps. writing an ant script just to get a test WAR out is just too much work.

Comment: another solution instead of creating an ant file would to go to the folder you want to wrap in WAR file and execute this command "jar -cvf name.war *" .

Comment: Thanks for this, a LOT simpler than configuring Maven or Ant (when it's not necesarily needed).

Answer (score 23):

We use Maven (Ant's big brother) for all our java projects, and it has a very nifty WAR plugin. Tutorials and usage can be found there.

It's a lot easier than Ant, fully compatible with Eclipse (use *maven eclipse:eclipse* to create Eclipse projects) and easy to configure.

[Maven's homepage](http://maven.apache.org/)

[Maven WAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

Sample Configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-alpha-2</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp/</outputDirectory>
        <workDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp/war/work</workDirectory>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        <cacheFile>${project.build.directory}/tmp/war/work/webapp-cache.xml</cacheFile>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>jsp</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
        <warName>Application</warName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I gave you your point back (though it wasn't I who removed it). Maven is certainly a reasonable choice if you happen to (want to?) fit into their particular version of "convention over configuration."

Comment: I happen to like it =) I'm working as CM on a pretty big project, and I appreciate having the grunt work of project configuration done for me. Also, the plugin support is wonderful. Being able to have a multi-module project up and running with a WAR-plugin, with Surefire and CheckStyle in five minutes is a treat.

Ant, while more open and arguably more powerful, is a hassle in comparison. Anyway, Maven is a subset to Ant, so if you need to do any scripting there, you're welcome.

Comment: Besides Maven's XML structure being based on ANT's, and ANT being incorporated as a subset of Maven.

Answer (score 15):

A war file is simply a jar file with a war extension, but what makes it work is how the contents is actually structured.

The J2EE/Java EE tutorial can be a start:

http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WebComponents3.html

And the Servlet specification contains the gory details:

http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/download.html

If you create a new web project in Eclipse (I am referring to the Java EE version), the structure is created for you and you can also tell it where your Appserver is installed and it will deploy and start the application for you.

Using the "Export->WAR file" option will let you save the war file.

Answer (score 12):

If you are not sure what to do and are starting from scratch then Maven can help get you started.

By following the the below steps you can get a new war project setup perfectly in eclipse.

1. Download and install [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.html)
2. Go the command line run: `mvn archetype:generate`
3. Follow the prompted steps - choosing the simple java web project (18) and a suitable name.
4. When it is finished run: `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
5. Start Eclipse. Choose File -> Import -> Existing project. Select the directory where you ran the mvn goals.
6. That's it you should now have a very good start to a war project in eclipse
7. You can create the war itself by running `mvn package` or deploy it by setting up a server in eclipse and simply adding adding the project to the server.

As some others have said the downside of using maven is that you have to use the maven conventions. But I think if you are just starting out, learning the conventions is a good idea before you start making your own. There's nothing to stop you changing/refactoring to your own preferred method at a later point.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following command outside the WEB-INF folder. This should create your war file and is the quickest method I know.

*(You will need JDK 1.7+ installed and environment variables that point to the bin directory of your JDK.)*

```
jar -cvf projectname.war *
```

[Reference Link](http://www.javatpoint.com/war-file)

Comment: If you receive `'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command` then try `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jar" -cvf projectname.war *`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Ant war task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use ant build code 
I use this for my project SMS

```
<property name="WEB-INF" value="${basedir}/WebRoot/WEB-INF" />
<property name="OUT" value="${basedir}/out" />
<property name="WAR_FILE_NAME" value="mywebapplication.war" />
<property name="TEMP" value="${basedir}/temp" />

<target name="help">
    <echo>
        --------------------------------------------------
        compile - Compile
        archive - Generate WAR file
        --------------------------------------------------
    </echo>
</target>

<target name="init">
    <delete dir="${WEB-INF}/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="${WEB-INF}/classes" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src" 
                destdir="${WEB-INF}/classes" 
                classpathref="libs">
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="archive" depends="compile">
    <delete dir="${OUT}" />
    <mkdir dir="${OUT}" />
    <delete dir="${TEMP}" />
    <mkdir dir="${TEMP}" />
    <copy todir="${TEMP}" >
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/WebRoot">
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <move file="${TEMP}/log4j.properties" 
                    todir="${TEMP}/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <war destfile="${OUT}/${WAR_FILE_NAME}" 
                    basedir="${TEMP}" 
                    compress="true" 
                    webxml="${TEMP}/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
    <delete dir="${TEMP}" />
</target>

<path id="libs">
    <fileset includes="*.jar" dir="${WEB-INF}/lib" />
</path>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to build it automatically using Eclipse. Of course if you have continuous integration environment Ant or Maven is recommended. The export alternative is not very convenient because you have to configure every time the export properties.

*STEPS:*

1. Enable "Project Archives" support; this might depend on your project (I used it on Java EE/Web project). Right-click project root directory; Configure -> Add Project Archives Support.
2. Go and create a new archive in the "Project Archives" top dir. You have only jar option, but name you archive *.war.
3. Configure Fileset-s, i.e what files to be included. Typical is to configure two filesets similar how the Web Deployment Assembly (project property) is configured.

   - copy /WebContent to /
   - copy /build/classes to WEB-INF/classes (create this fileset after you define the WEB-INF/classes directory in the archive)
4. You might need to tweek the fileset exclude property depending where you placed some of the config files or you might need more filesets, but the idea is that once you configured this you don't need to change it.
5. Build the archive manually or publish directly to server; but is also automatically built for you by Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Another common option is gradle.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

To build your war file in a web app:

In build.gradle, add:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```

Then:

```
./gradlew war
```

Use the layout from accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution which also refreshes the Eclipse workspace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project" default="default">    
    <target name="default">
        <war destfile="target/MyApplication.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="src/main/java" />
            <fileset dir="web/WEB-INF/views" />
            <lib dir="web/WEB-INF/lib"/>
            <classes dir="target/classes" />
        </war>
        <eclipse.refreshLocal resource="MyApplication/target" depth="infinite"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic Shell code for creating WAR files from a standard Eclipse dynamic Web Project. Uses RAM File system (/dev/shm) on a Linux platform.

```
#!/bin/sh

UTILITY=$(basename $0)

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    echo "usage: $UTILITY [-s] <web-app-directory>..."
    echo "       -s ..... With source"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" == "-s" ] ; then
    WITH_SOURCE=1
    shift
fi

while [ ! -z "$1" ] ; do
    WEB_APP_DIR=$1

    shift

    if [ ! -d $WEB_APP_DIR ] ; then
        echo "\"$WEB_APP_DIR\" is not a directory"
        continue
    fi

    if [ ! -d $WEB_APP_DIR/WebContent ] ; then
        echo "\"$WEB_APP_DIR\" is not a Web Application directory"
        continue
    fi

    TMP_DIR=/dev/shm/${WEB_APP_DIR}.$$.tmp
    WAR_FILE=/dev/shm/${WEB_APP_DIR}.war

    mkdir $TMP_DIR

    pushd $WEB_APP_DIR > /dev/null
    cp -r WebContent/* $TMP_DIR
    cp -r build/* $TMP_DIR/WEB-INF
    [ ! -z "$WITH_SOURCE" ] && cp -r src/* $TMP_DIR/WEB-INF/classes
    cd $TMP_DIR > /dev/null
    [ -e $WAR_FILE ] && rm -f $WAR_FILE
    jar cf $WAR_FILE .
    ls -lsF $WAR_FILE
    popd > /dev/null

    rm -rf $TMP_DIR
done
```

Answer (score -3):

**Making War file in Eclips Gaynemed of grails web project **

1.Import project:

2.Change the datasource.groovy file

Like this: url="jdbc:postgresql://18.247.120.101:8432/PGMS"

2.chnge AppConfig.xml

3.kill the Java from Task Manager:

4. run clean comand in eclips
5. run 'prod war' fowllowed by project name.
6. Check the log file and find the same .war file in directory of workbench with same date.

Comment: Oops.  This is probably from their team notes.