# How to setup a war file with different directories in an Ant Script

Tags: eclipse, ant, war, ear

Pretty new to this so bear with me.  I've gotten my Ant build.xml to run and populate everything that I want, but my content (js, css, jsp, etc) is just jammed into the WAR at its topmost directory.  I'm looking to put this content into the WEB-INF folder that I would need to make within the war.  Here's what I have so far as a reference.  If I could just see an example of how to do this I think I would be good.  Tried to follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files), is that dist setup what I am missing??

```
    <war warfile="${build}/${project.name}.war" webxml="${appconf}/web.xml">
        <classes dir="${appconf}/classes" />
        <fileset dir="${appcontent}" includes="jsp/**,js/**,images/**,css/**,tg/**" excludes="**/*.~js,**/*.~jav,**/*.java,cvs,annotation">
            <patternset id="jsp_images_package">
                <include name="**/*.jsp,**/*.js,**/*.gif,**/*.html,**/*.css"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.~js,**/*.~jav"/>
            </patternset>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${appcontent}" includes="WEB-INF/lib/*.jar,WEB-INF/*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${appcontent}" includes="WEB-INF/lib/*.css"/>
        <fileset dir="${appcontent}" includes="docs/*.doc"/>
    </war>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use in this case is `<zipfileset>`.  It should look something like this (Your structure is weird, so I can't tell exactly where you want files).

```
<war warfile="${build}/${project.name}.war" webxml="${appconf}/web.xml">
    <classes dir="${appconf}/classes" />
    <zipfileset dir="${appcontent}/jsp" includes="**/*.jsp" prefix="WEB-INF"/>
    <zipfileset dir="${appcontent}/js" includes="**/*.js" prefix="WEB-INF"/>
    <zipfileset dir="${appcontent}/css" includes="**/*.css" prefix="WEB-INF"/>
    <fileset dir="${appcontent}">
        <include name="docs/*.doc"/>
        <include name="images/**"/>
        <include name="WEB-INF/*.jar"/>
        <include name="WEB-INF/lib/*.jar"/>
        <include name="WEB-INF/lib/*.css"/>
    </fileset>
</war>
```

Comment: eh dont worry about the struct, this is great.  So from the looks of it what I was missing is that prefix command.  So that will put it in the correct folder for me.

Comment: Have any good links that explain how to do this correctly?  I couldn't find a good API/explanation on this for the life of me.

Comment: Don't worry, I have a hard time finding out what Ant can do myself.  So the prefix will add that folder path to the relative paths of the files specified in "includes."