# Tomcat webapp folder is ruined when putting a new war file

Tags: tomcat, deployment

Usually, when I put an updated WAR file in Tomcat's `webapps` folder, the appropriate webapp is automatically updated.

But sometimes, when I put in an updated WAR file, a strange thing happens: most of that webapp's folder is deleted, except some random collection of files. Of course in this case the webapp no longer works. To make it work, I must stop Tomcat, delete the folder of that webapp entirely, then restart Tomcat.

I tried to stop the webapp from the Tomcat manager before putting the WAR file in `webapps` - it didn't help.

I tried to change `autodeploy` and/or `unpackwars` to false, but then the webapp was not updated at all when I put in the new warfile.

I also tried to use Jenkins' deployment plugin, but the same problem happened.

System spec: Tomcat 7 on Windows 2003.

Answer (score 3):

According to Tomcat 7 configuration guide: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic%20Application%20Deployment

> "**Updating** a WAR file will trigger an undeploy of the application, with
>   the removal of any associated expanded directory, context file and
>   work directory. Any current user sessions will not be persisted... The
>   application will be redeployed the next time the auto deployer checks
>   for changes."

Probably, the problem is that the auto-deployer still hasn't finished to remove the expanded directory, while another thread started re-deploying it.

My workaround is to delete the old war-file, wait until the directory is removed, and only then put the new war-file, since:

> "**Deleting** a WAR file will trigger an undeploy of the application, with
>   the removal of any associated expanded directory, context file and
>   work directory. Any current user sessions will not be persisted."

Answer (score 0):

## Sounds like "antiResourceLocking"

***Disclaimer:*** 1. Yes, I know this is an old question. 2. Completely untested.

I have not tried this, so this is untested purely "by the books" stuff. Here goes.

The [Tomcat7 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) (archived [here](https://archive.fo/C9YCo)) at least mentions that you need extra steps for hot deploy on Windows. Namely...

> on Windows, this assumes that anti-locking features (see
>   Context configuration) are enabled, otherwise it is not possible to
>   delete the resources of a running web application.

...and the appropriate configuration switch seems to be something called `antiResourceLocking`, which apparently...

> allows full webapp hot deploy and undeploy on platforms or configurations where file locking can occur

*(Source [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html). Archived [here](https://archive.fo/4pEH3).)*

And I'm not sure, but all of this does indeed sound a bit like *"undefined behavior can happen if you try to hot-deploy on Windows WITHOUT antiResourceLocking=true"*. And that sounds just terrible.

### Further reading

- **Matrix.** Judging by the matrix in the documentation, I think it's quite complicated.
  *(So my personal bottom line here is: I will just NOT use automatic-deployment, unless I absolutely have to. And rather do what you did and manually delete DIRs and unpack WARs.)*

  - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/automatic-deployment.html#New_files
    (Archived [here](https://archive.fo/wGelj#selection-677.0-677.9).)