# Steps needed to deploy war on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I have spring source tool with Maven. And I have one Java project which I want to deploy on Heroku.
Can anybody tell me steps to deploy on Heroku?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 15):

1. Create *war* file in Maven. You can do this by referring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1004210/3708384)
2. Install the Heroku Toolbelt from [here](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)
3. Open the command prompt (for Windows) and type:

   ```
   heroku login
   ```

   It will prompt to enter user name  and password. Enter the credentials of your heroku account.
4. Now, to install the *heroku-deploy* plugin, enter the code:

   ```
   heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy
   ```
5. Now deploy the *war* file to the *heroku server* by this code:

   ```
   heroku deploy:war --war <path_to_war_file> --app <app_name>
   ```
6. If you are in an application directory, the `--app` parameter can be omitted:

   ```
   heroku deploy:war --war <path_to_war_file>
   ```

Your App will be successfully deployed to the heroku server.

Comment: This helps me a lot. I was planning on hosting JIRA on a heroku server, the --app option is what made it a bit clearer for me how to deploy the JIRA war file on a heroku app. Although I'm a bit unclear on how to create a new app without an actual working source code base.

Answer (score 5):

It's all well explained here :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java

Comment: Thank you Felix for your answer.But it is in Beta version..right?

Comment: Yes, Heroku's "cedar" stack that support Java is currently in beta.

Answer (score 4):

#### How to deploy war file to Heroku

- Register Heroku account
- Install heroku-cli
- Install JDK if needed
- Install heroku-cli-deploy plugin using command:

  ```
  heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy
  ```
- Login to heroku in command line:

  ```
  heroku login
  ```
- Create app using command:

  ```
  heroku apps:create <app_name>
  ```
- Deploy war file using this command:

  ```
  heroku war:deploy <path_to_war_file> --app <app_name>
  ```
- Open app using command:

  ```
  heroku open -a <app_name>
  ```

---

Reference: [Heroku Deploy War/Jar](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli-deploy)

Answer (score 0):

This url shows exactly how to deploy a war file on heroku:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy