# Initialise a Java program and listen for queries

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm writing an application that uses the Stanford CoreNLP library among many other library. The application takes a URL, extracts text from it, and then process the the text using CoreNLP. The problem is that the CoreNLP library takes a lot of time to load its models into memory before annotating the text. I'am looking for the best way to do the initialisation step only one time and the next time when I want to use the app and I enter a URL it doesn't load the models again.

Comment: to get a useful answer, you should explain more about how you're launching the app - not having used that API myself, it's hard to say, but you can keep a JVM running with the initialized library in memory, and re-use the same JVM each time somehow

Comment: I'am asking for the best way to do it all I need is that the application will take a URL and process it as quickly as possible and wait for other urls (the results will be stored in a database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to run your application inside a container - [Servlet Container](http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/05/14/java_webserver.html) or even [Web Container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) like [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)? You can package your application as a [simple WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files) then the container will initialize all the java classes once and assuming that you expose a servlet that would trigger the NLP processing for a single URL you will save the initialization time for all the consequent NLP processing calls.

**Edit:**

You do not have to use the servlets.
Alternatively, you can do one of the following:

1. Run in you WAR a loop that would read URLs from some configuration source (DB or file) and for each URL will do the NLP and parsing (storing the results for later analysis?)
2. More advanced solution could include your existing java program cobined with [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) that will run one NLP+parser every X seconds/minutes/hours etc.  Even more advanced version would be using Quartz with [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/).

Good Luck!

Comment: Ok I had the same idea, but is there a way to do the same thing without servlets?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know how instead of scheduling I watch a file for changes (i.e when I add a new URL to the file the program will run using the added URLs)

Comment: @madmed, you can check some code here http://geosoft.no/software/filemonitor/FileMonitor.java.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example from their page [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), the following is used to annotate a text:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
String text = ... // Add your text here!
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(document);
```

Therefore, you can create an object and parse a dummy text when the app is initializing. you ignore the results of the operation as the purpose is to load the required modules when the app is loading. after that, you can keep the "pipeline" object and reference it for additional annotation operations when needed.