# java servlet on AWS ec2

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, amazon-ec2

I'm writing a `client-server` application.
The client application will run on android device, and I'm using `ec2` with `tomcat6` as a server. I wrote a server application which I want to run constantly on the server.
How do I do it?
Is this implemented with `servlet`, and how?
Also, I'm not sure, who starts the server-application once the server is up?

I have a basic knowledge of how servlets work, I created an `http servlet` which adds rows to database (`RDS`) through `html` page.

Comment: Yes, you can build a servlet and run it in tomcat (or jetty/jboss/glassfish...), and open it up for public access (listening on an external IP). And you're in charge of making sure your servers are up, so you will have to learn how to deploy your servlets into tomcat and start your servers (usually done with startup scripts). Unfortunately your question is very broad, so I think you should read the [Java Servlet tutorial first](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).

Comment: thanx for your answer... "so you will have to learn how to deploy your servlets into tomcat and start your servers" that's exactly what i'm asking.... how to do that?

Comment: That's a pretty loaded question, because I don't know the extent of your knowledge. Have you ever built a `.war` file? Ever used a build tool like Maven or sbt or Ivy2? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files is one question about creating war files. My favorite build tool for creating Java-based web projects is [`sbt`](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki), which will create wars (and deploy them) for you.

Comment: i didnt do any of those, i'll check out the link you gave me. and if i need help, i'll ask here again
thank you very much!!!

Comment: Read through some of those links, try out some stuff - if you run into problems, post a targeted question and you'll get better help. Very broad questions tend either to get closed or ignored because they're hard to give a solid answer to.

Comment: You are right!! thank you very much, you've been very helpful!