# Eclipse: Dependencies for .war generation

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, war

I have 3 projects

1. XXX.web : a Dynamic Web Project
2. XXX.persistence: a normal java project
3. XXX.t1: a normal java project

Projects 2 and 3 have other dependencies with jars inside of them.

Project1, XXX.web, has imported the other two projects, XXX.presistence and XXX.t1 using:

- Right Click on XXX.web -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Projects -> add -> XXX.t1

and

- Right Click on XXX.web -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Projects -> add -> XXX.t1

When I run the XXX.web, Eclipse resolves the dependencies (at runtime I think, correct me if wrong).

However I want to generate a .war file so that my web project, which has dependencies to the other two projects works fine. Does eclipse to this by itself or do I have to manually copy the dependency jars in t1 and persistence to web's lib folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create war files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ant to build your war file. Ant can compile your projects and build a war from them. Look here for more info: [How to create war files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files)