# Creating a SOAP service which can be deployed as war on JBOSS

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, axis, war-filedeployment

I am totally new to SOAP services. I wanted to know how to create a SOAP service using Axis/CXF (anything is fine), but the end-product should be a WAR file which i can deploy on JBOSS 7.

I tried but was able to reach till WSDL using the following example http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/ but it doesnt say how to generate a war file :-(

Can you please suggest link or example on how to create a SOAP service from scratch.

Thanks and regards,

Rohit

Comment: Hi Rohit: if you had googled for it a bit you'd have found: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreateJAXWSEndpointFromAWSDLFile?_sscc=t

Comment: and tutorial how to create WAR file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks a lot. I was able to generate the classes using Wsconsume but now i want to import it in eclipse with maven, can you please suggest what maven project archetype should i use so that i can copy paste the generated calles in their place

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, you can specify that during you 'build' phase in you .pom file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <unpackTypes>war</unpackTypes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```