# how to deploy a eclipse dynamic web page in tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I developed dynamic web page in eclipse.I also configured apache tomcat in eclipse juno.In eclipse it run on server fine.I don't know how to deploy the dynamic web page in other system tomcat server.My folder structure.

```
                 Tomcat 7.0
                     -webapps
                         -Myproject-Folder
                             -WEB-INF
                                 -classes
                                 -lib
                                 -web.xml
```

Comment: Copy your *.war file to the tomcat's webapps folder.

Comment: @Sambuca the *.war file contains src file?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a folder in your tomcat **webapps** folder
Then create another folder WEB-INF and index.html
Then in WEB-INF folder create three other folders classes,src,lib and web.xml

In classes folder keep all the .class files.
If you want to keep the source files then these should be placed in the src folder.
In the lib folder keep all the necessary jar files like activation.jar,mail.jar(if you are using java mail Api).
Now map correctly in web.xml 
Now if your web.xml is correctly mapped then open a browser and type

```
http://localhost:8080/your_folder_name
```

8080 is the default port number.

Comment: ... what? **no**. you're not supposed to put your source files under tomcat or create a folder for them.

Comment: @eis its optional you all know,I am just telling the use of all folders

Answer (score 0):

just copy the "Myproject-Folder" to the "webapps" folder of any tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to deploy it, you can just copy the folder under "webapps" of your current Tomcat or package it into .war and put that under webapps folder of the target Tomcat.