# Deploy web application on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I created a simple web application in eclipse which connect to sql server. I downloaded the sql driver and added it to build path like this:

> Build Path->Configure Build Path->Add External JARs.

When I run my application on Tomcat I get exception: `ClassNotFoundException.` I think that I know what it reason is `(the folder WEB-INF->lib of my application is empty)`. When I put jar file of driver in `WEB-INF->lib`  - everything is good. How I can add jar file(sql driver) to folder `WEB-INF->lib` of my application using eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse just adds it to the build path of the local workspace, which won't work on the application server, as you've noticed. You should use a compile tool such as Maven, SBT, Ant, etc. to build your WAR and handle the dependencies. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files) for more information.

Comment: Are you running the webapplication in tomcat within eclipse?

Comment: What about deploying it manually = copying the files to respective directory in Tomcat installation?

Comment: @Octopus yes,I'm running the webapplication in tomcat within eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the JDBC driver JAR in [Tomcat-install-root]/lib will solve your problem, and you can do that outside of Eclipse.