# Best way to deploy enyojs web applcation ? Is it possible to make war out of it and deploy on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, enyo

I'd like to know various way of deploying enyojs application on my webserver ?

and i'm more interested making war(since i'm a more of java developer) out of it. is it possible?

Since I'm newbie. I've no clue about these stuffs. May be help with easy and simple way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to minimize your application and the framework.  If you've built your application using [Bootplate](https://github.com/enyojs/bootplate) you can easily create a deployable directory using `tools/deploy`.  If not, you might want to consider adapting it to Bootplate for the easier deploy step. For more information, check the deployment section of the Bootplate docs here: https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Bootplate#preparing-for-deployment

You might check this other article on creating war files: [How to create war files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files)  I assume that the jsp page sections would just be replaced with your deployable Enyo files, but you'll probably want to check that assumption.