# How to solve - HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java, hibernate, class, servlets, http-status-code-500

> I keep getting this error and i dont know what to do, I'm a student, please be cool with me guys!

HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    br.com.sky.iTvMC.util.JPAUtil.(JPAUtil.java:9)
    br.com.sky.iTvMC.controler.CanalClienteControle.processRequest(CanalClienteControle.java:37)
    br.com.sky.iTvMC.controler.CanalClienteControle.doPost(CanalClienteControle.java:79)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    br.com.sky.iTvMC.util.JPAUtil.(JPAUtil.java:9)
    br.com.sky.iTvMC.controler.CanalClienteControle.processRequest(CanalClienteControle.java:37)
    br.com.sky.iTvMC.controler.CanalClienteControle.doPost(CanalClienteControle.java:79)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 logs.

Comment: Well, the message says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence` so the according jars are probably not on the classpath.

Comment: If you have created a war file to deploy your web app have look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files) question to get your classes and libs into the classpath

Comment: How do i put this jar on the classpath? i don't know how to do it.